# the dnssec-keygen works very slow on Centos if we run it with inputting domain name only

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, bind, openssl

From this ISC BIND article example:

https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00626/0/Inline-Signing-in-ISC-BIND-9.9.0-Examples.html

```
$ dnssec-keygen example.com
    Generating key pair........................+++++
    ...............++++++ 
    Kexample.com.+005+17262
$ dnssec-keygen -fk example.com
    Generating key pair.....................................+++++
    ........................................................+++ 
    Kexample.com.+005+44139
```

I tried them on Centos 5 (x64) and saw that dnssec-keygen works so slow.

If I add another option argument, it work immediately.

Example:

```
dnssec-keygen -r random.data example.com
```

It does not happen on the Windows OS.

After trying to debug, I see it stick around the

```
RSA_generate_key_ex(rsa, key->key_size, e, &cb))
```

in the

```
 lib\dns\opensslrsa_link.c
```

I have tried to sent mail to ISC but they don't reply anymore.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably be a lack of entropy, not uncommon especially on virtualised and/or mostly idle systems.

Without checking the code it might be that the random input needed for generating proper keys is retrieved from /dev/random which IIRC is unlike /dev/urandom in that it blocks when there's unsufficient entropy (i.e. randomness) available. You can check the number of bits available in `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`.

You can help increase the amount of entropy by generating interupts (hit the keyboard, play with the mouse, run find / , compile a new kernel etc.), get a hardware random number generator, or, if your security requirements aren't very high install rngd-tools and use /dev/urandom as a work-around to increase the amount of pseudo entropy: `rngd -r /dev/urandom -o /dev/random -b`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, I have never needed to try "dnssec-keygen example.com". Thanks for helping me to understand the issue clearly:)